# Chamando função a partir do nome da mesma em uma classe PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Estou criando uma aplicação onde eu preciso chamar a função com base no nome dela dentro da classe. a intenção de usar dessa forma é que eu possa chamar estas funções através de ajax e o servidor vai entender sem que seja necessário fazer um `switch` ou algo do tipo. Basicamente o que eu tenho é isso

```
class MinhaClasse {
    var foo = 'ola mundo';
    var bar = 'teste para o stack';
    public function index($fn = 'a')
    {
        $result = $this->$fn(); // <-- é isso que eu quero
    }
    private function a()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
    private function b()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

Basicamente, preciso que a partir de uma string ou algum elemento que eu mandar para a função `index($fn)` ele execute uma função dentro da minha classe. Alguém teria alguma forma de fazer isso?

**EDIT**: hoje, para que consiga chegar nisso, sou obrigado a fazer um switch, o que polui o código e ainda me obriga a ficar editando se houver mudanças, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class MinhaClasse { //com switch tosco...
    var foo = 'ola mundo';
    var bar = 'teste para o stack';
    public function index($fn = 'a')
    {
        switch($fn){
            case 'b': 
               $result = $this->b();
            break;
            default : 
               $result = $this->a();
            break;
        };

        echo $result;
    }
    private function a()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
    private function b()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode chamar a função usando `{}`

Ficaria assim:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    var foo = 'ola mundo';
    var bar = 'teste para o stack';
    public function index($fn = 'a')
    {
        $result = $this->{$fn}(); // <-- é isso que eu quero
    }
    private function a()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
    private function b()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: isso mesmo, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: Gostei do `{$fn}`. É uma sintaxe pouco conhecida, mas que ajuda a evitar diferentes interpretações principalmente agora com as [mudanças no PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php).

Answer (score 6):

Pode fazer isto:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    var $foo = 'ola mundo';
    var $bar = 'teste para o stack';
    public function index($fn = a) {
        $result = $this->$fn(); // <-- é isso que eu quero
    }
    private function a() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
    private function b() {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
$classe = new MinhaClasse();
$classe->index();
$classe->index(b);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2Ghkpj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hdvjexzh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/CallByName.php).

Prefiro esta forma por não ficar usando *strings*, você passa o próprio símbolo da função.

Comment: Realmente faz mais sentido. A outra solução é igual por variável dentro de string, tipo `$a = "$parametro";`, só faz o interpretador do PHP processar uma coisa a mais pra chegar no mesmo que o seu código faz. Só não entendi como é que tem -2 votos na sua resposta, meio anormal isso. Ou é de gente que não faz a mínima idéia de como o PHP trabalha, ou é sacanagem mesmo.

Comment: Removi meu downvote, eu fui ler a respeito do downvote e vi que é para o caso da resposta estar errada e/ou perigosamente errada. Desculpe meu equivoco, O contrário do que dizem que não estou aqui para tumultuar . Mas acredito que a sua resposta ainda assim não é a melhor pela falta de tipagem, com string é melhor para trabalhar, mas fica as 2 maneiras.